# The collectionOperations of API Platform remove the POST route

Tags: php, api, symfony, routes, api-platform.com

I begin with API platform and I noticed that when I write my "collectionOperations" in my "personnes" entity, the POST route is removed from the swagger. (same for my route which get all "personnes").

In my entity (with attribute) :

```
#[ApiResource(
collectionOperations: [
    'me' => [
        'pagination_enabled' => false,
        'path' => '/me',
        'method' => 'get',
        'controller' => MeController::class,
    ]
],
normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['read:User']]
```

]

Someone can tel me how I can get it back or know why it's removed ?

Answer (score -1):

I think it’s because you define a collectionOperations. If you define collectionOperations like you did with GET /me you override the default behavior and you need to define POST and GET too.

```
#[ApiResource(
collectionOperations: [
   'me' => [
    'pagination_enabled' => false,
    'path' => '/me',
    'method' => 'get',
    'controller' => MeController::class,
    ], 
    'get',
    'post'
]
```

From [documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#enabling-and-disabling-operations): “If no operation is specified, all default CRUD operations are automatically registered”

It’s the case for the itemOperation, you didn’t define operation and they all (GET,PUT,DELETE) appears in swagger.